# jquery window.parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can use this just fine in a window

```
$('#dropDownSpan').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

but how can I use it in another window which is child of this window or may be opened by this window.

I tried:

```
 $window.parent.('#dropDownSpan').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

but that didnt work, any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#dropDownSpan', window.parent.document).css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to interact with the parent page which had opened up a tinymce popup that I created and I needed to use this: `group = $('#edit-og-groups', window.opener.document).val();`
I had no luck with `window.parent.document`.